# Canvas in a web app and save it to display it in a mobile app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, drag-and-drop

I'm going to be specific, and I hope I can explain the issue I'm having and what I want to achieve. I have two projects, a web app with React and a React Native app. The project involves Drag and Drop functionality. In the web app with React, I use react-konva and Konva for Drag and Drop. Now, what I want to achieve is as follows: in the web app, there's a part where I render several elements that can be draggable, and let's say someone changes the positions of each element and arranges them in a way they prefer. Now, what information should I store in my API (where I manage the database) to retrieve it from the mobile app and render the shapes on the screen as they were in the web app?

I have several doubts about this because, for example: the screens of the web app change their width and height, and I want to render everything in the width and height of any mobile screen. In this case, should I scale the sizes so that it adapts to the width?

I'll put a simple code.

```
import { Stage, Layer, Rect, Circle } from 'react-konva';

export default function Drag () {
    return (
        <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
            <Layer>
                <Rect
                    x={20}
                    y={20}
                    width={100}
                    height={100}
                    fill="red"
                    draggable
                />
                <Circle x={200} y={100} radius={50} fill="green" />
            </Layer>
        </Stage>
    );
}
```

and let's suppose someone moves the figures like this (in the web app)
[image: image web app]

and what I want is to save the information (which I suppose will be x, y of the figures) that helps me render like this now but in the mobile app

[image: image mobile app]

How do I achieve that? I hope someone can help me, if the problem cannot be explained, tell me in a comment and I will edit the post